# Big brackets are always opening and square when using fontspec with MnSymbol

Tags: xetex, fontspec, brackets

I have here a strange problem I don't get.
When using the [`fontspec`](http://ctan.org/pkg/fontspec) package in combination with [`MnSymbol`](http://ctan.org/pkg/mnsymbol) package all big brackets in math mode are square and opening...
when I deactivate one of the packages the problem is gone!

Here an example of the problem:

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{etex}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{mathtools,amssymb,amsmath}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{MnSymbol}


% the next line makes the definition of \mathdollar from MnSymbol void.
\undef\mathdollar 

\begin{document}


Big brackets are messed up while normal brackets still work:
\begin{equation*}
    \begin{pmatrix} 
      1 & 2 & 3  \\
      1 & 2 & 3  \\
      1 & 2 & 3     
    \end{pmatrix}
    = \left( \sum_{i=1}^{n-1} i \right)
    = \left( n \right)
    = \big( naaaarf \big)
    = (all fine) 
\end{equation*}


\begin{equation*}
      \left[ \sum_{i=1}^{n-1} i \right]
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

And here the result:
[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`MnSymbol` changes all the delimiter codes, but also `fontspec` does and later than `MnSymbol`, so the problem arises.

A possible solution is to load `fontspec` with the `no-math` option; another one is not using `MnSymbol` at all.

```
\usepackage[no-math]{fontspec}
```

[image]